# Updating File passed to MediaPlayer android

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app in which I have to update the audio file passed to the mediaplayer. It is like buffering except i do not have an URL to give as i am taking care of the file transfer.

I have looked at the mediaplayer class's documentation and understood the prepareAsync needs to be called in case of streams but what happens is that only a small initial part gets played, also it takes a lot of time to start. So from what i understood about mediaplayer till now is that it prepares the file (i think it decodes the data) and passes it to a lower level player like audiotrack to play it, it does decodes any further data that is added to the file.

Is there a workaround as android does support streaming also are there some other library that i can use?